# Inserindo data atual em php

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando inserir a data atual a medida que a pessoa se cadastra porém não queria que o usuario informasse estes dados e sim que fossem inseridos através de alguma função com mysql, para ficar gravado a data em que o fornecedor foi registrado. Porém tentei de algumas formas e não consegui, procurei aqui no fórum e também não consegui então criei a pergunta

```
<?php  
        if(isset($_POST['enviar_for'])){

                $id = $_POST['id'];
                $fornecedor = $_POST['fornecedor'];
                $observacoes = $_POST['observacoes'];
                $data_cadastro = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['data_cadastro']));

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM cadfor WHERE id_pessoa = '$id' "; 
                $resulta = $conn->query($sql);
                $row = $resulta->fetch_assoc();

                if ($resulta->num_rows > 0 ){
                    $result_endereco = "UPDATE cadfor SET tipo_endereco = '$tipo_endereco', cep = '$cep ', tipo_logr = '$tipo_logr', nome_logr = '$nome_logr', nume_logr = '$nume_logr', comp_logr = '$comp_logr', cidade = '$cidade', bairro = '$bairro', uf = '$uf' WHERE id_pessoa = '$id' ";
                } else {
                    $result_endereco = "INSERT INTO cadfor(id_pessoa, fornecedor, observacoes, data_cadastro) VALUES ('$id', '$fornecedor', '$observacoes', 'NOW()' )";
                }
                $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result_endereco);
                echo $result_endereco;
        }
  ?>
```

Comment: Retire as aspas da função `NOW()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `NOW()` do MySQL retorna a data atual.

Você pode fazer assim:

```
$result_endereco = "INSERT INTO cadfor(id_pessoa, fornecedor, observacoes, data_cadastro) VALUES ('$id', '$fornecedor', '$observacoes', NOW())";
```

Pra funcionar, a coluna `data_cadastro` tem que ser do tipo DATE, DATETIME ou TIMESTAMP.

Comment: este formato não foi, vou atualizar o código, ela é do tipo date mesmo mas não foi

Comment: Fiz um comentário na sua pergunta, olha lá.

Comment: obrigado funcionou, nem tinha me atentado as aspas

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar a função `date()` de php passando o formato que você quer.

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: este formato não foi, vou atualizar o código

Comment: Os formatos são diversos, tem que ver qual é a sua necessidade: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php

Comment: eu queria inserir a data atual  sem que o usuario tivesse necessidade de informar, mas joguei isto dentro do meu codigo e não funcionou mesmo o campo sendo date e eu informando que ele é date em php

Comment: se você armazenar o valor retornado da função date em uma varável, o usuário não vai precisar preencher. A função date pega a data e horas atuais do seu servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar  isto:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: este formato não foi, vou atualizar o código